# get other column using window function

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Here is an sql statement I'm using:

```sql
with product_table as (
    select * from data
    where product_name='x' 
    and datetime between parseDateTimeBestEffort('2023-01-25 10:00:00.0')
                and parseDateTimeBestEffort('2023-01-25 11:00:00.0')
    order by datetime)
, max_price_table as (
    select 
        datetime
        , max(price) over wndw as max_price
    from product_table
    window wndw as (order by toFloat64(datetime) range
        between 1 following and 60 following)
)
select * from max_price_table
```

If I run this, I get the correct max price but the datetime is not the datetime at which the max price occurs. Is there a way I could get both the max price and the max price datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
create table data( datetime Datetime, price Float64)
Engine=Memory
as select toDateTime('2023-01-25') + number, number 
  from numbers(10);


WITH
    product_table AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM data
        WHERE (datetime >= '2023-01-25') AND (datetime <= '2023-01-26')
    ),
    max_price_table AS
    (
        SELECT
            datetime,
            price,
            argMax(datetime, price) OVER wndw AS max_price_datetime,
            max(price) OVER wndw AS max_price
        FROM product_table
        WINDOW wndw AS (ORDER BY toFloat64(datetime) ASC RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING)
    )
SELECT *
FROM max_price_table

┌────────────datetime─┬─price─┬──max_price_datetime─┬─max_price─┐
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:00 │     0 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:05 │         5 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:01 │     1 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:06 │         6 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:02 │     2 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:07 │         7 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:03 │     3 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:08 │         8 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:04 │     4 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:09 │         9 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:05 │     5 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:09 │         9 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:06 │     6 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:09 │         9 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:07 │     7 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:09 │         9 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:08 │     8 │ 2023-01-25 00:00:09 │         9 │
│ 2023-01-25 00:00:09 │     9 │ 1970-01-01 07:00:00 │         0 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```